golang time.Time binary encode decode inconsistency
Im doing data serialization/deserialization in Go, what I noticed is, time.Time objects are different when you serialize deserialize them. I tried couple things, such as converting timestamps to UTC before and after serialize/deserialize, but I couldn't achieve what I wanted (even though their int64 representations are the same)
serialization:
...
    err = binary.Write(&buf, binary.LittleEndian, tx.LockTime.UTC().Unix())
...

original time struct
time.Time(2024-07-29T08:17:41+03:00, +1956460){wall: 13952687508967845872, ext: 1956460, loc: *(*time.Location)(0x10448fdc0)}

deserialization:
...
    var lockTime int64
    err = binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &lockTime)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    tx.LockTime = time.Unix(lockTime, 0).UTC()
...

deserialized time struct
time.Time(2024-07-29T05:17:41Z){wall: 0, ext: 63857827061, loc: *time.Location nil}

Why is this happening, and how to solve it?

See Monotonic Clocks.

In addition to monotonic time mentioned already converting to UTC deliberately clears the time zone. You basically cannot to what you try but you probably don't need to serialize monotonic clocks anyway (this makes no sense).

Another issue is the program encodes time with a resolution of one second.  Use UnixNano to ensure that the time is encoded with full resolution.

the time.time struct in Go has a complex internal representation which includes the wall clock time and an explicit location when you serialize it by converting it to unix timestamp with Unix() you lose the wall clock time and location information this is why the deserialized time.time appears different internally even though it represents the same point in time.
to fix this issue you should ensure that the location information is preserved during serialization and deserialization one way to achieve tis is to serialize the time in a format that includes the location information like RFC339
serialization should looks like this:
err = binary.Write(&buf, binary.LittleEndian, []byte(tx.LockTime.Format(time.RFC3339)))

and deserialization should looks like this:
var timeBytes [len(time.RFC3339)]byte
err = binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &timeBytes)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
tx.LockTime, err = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, string(timeBytes[:]))
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

if you need to use binary format you'll have to serialize both the unix timestamp and location like this:

err = binary.Write(&buf, binary.LittleEndian, tx.LockTime.Unix())
if err != nil {
    // handle error here
}
location := tx.LockTime.Location().String()
err = binary.Write(&buf, binary.LittleEndian, int32(len(location)))
if err != nil {
    // handle error here
}
err = binary.Write(&buf, binary.LittleEndian, []byte(location))
if err != nil {
    // handle error here
}

and deserizile like this:
var lockTime int64
err = binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &lockTime)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
var locLen int32
err = binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &locLen)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
locBytes := make([]byte, locLen)
err = binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &locBytes)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
location, err := time.LoadLocation(string(locBytes))
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
tx.LockTime = time.Unix(lockTime, 0).In(location)


I hope this helps

I don't want to serialize any other information(location etc.) other than timestamp

@sekomer, then do just that: ask the value to return to you the raw number of seconds/nanoseconds and serialize that number. For instance, timeval.UTC().UnixNano() could be a good start. Note that, as already said, the information about the time value's location (timezone) is lost. It may or may not be relevant but you must think about it (at least because displaying time usually depends on the location).
